# Can you sub collagen protein for whey protein isolate in baking?

Tags: baking, gluten-free, whey

I have Vital Proteins Collagen Peptides Unflavored, which is 90% protein (9g protein per 10 g serving).

The whey protein isolates I've seen are also approximately 90% protein. Because I already have the collagen, I'd like to substitute it for whey protein isolate in recipes for gluten-free baked goods. I've searched this topic online and am coming up blank. I have yet to find a GF baked recipe that uses collagen in the same way that they're using the WPI. Anyone out there have any experience/knowledge with subbing collagen for the isolate? Thanks for the help, Mary

Note: I am specifically asking about isolate, not just whey protein.

Comment: I'd be concerned with collagen's high glycine, proline and hydroxyproline content: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagen  Aminoacetic acid, AKA glycine, isn't even chiral, and hydroxy proline is a post translational modification. Your collagen Was might behave very differently from the more balanced whey product.

Comment: What is the whey protein for in your recipes? Are you using it as an emulsifier, for texture or simply to increase the protein content of the result?

Comment: I would be concerned because of food science sources insisting that, when collagen melts at 69 C, it becomes gelatine. But I don't know how the commercially extracted collagen relates to the collagen in meat, so I find the question very interesting and hope that somebody will be able to answer it.

Comment: Collagen is not used for its protein substance but for it's gelling capability. If you substitute with whey protein you'll probably lose a lot of texture.

Comment: Do you have any example recipes where whey protein isolate is used? I bake extensively with whey protein isolate (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/101137/54812), and also have collagen peptides available to test.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to whey protein, not specifically whey protein isolate, Carolyn Ketchum writes as follows:  "I do not recommend using collagen peptides or collagen protein powder as a replacement for why or egg white protein....the baked goods always become quite gummy and difficult to cook through."  Ultimate Guide to Keto Baking

Answer (score 1):

I do not know scientifically what the differences are when used in baking, but I have used collagen hydrosylate as a replacement for WPI in keto baking. I cannot tolerate dairy, so I have had no choice, and cannot compare the results directly. I saw the Bulletproof Blog using collagen hyrosylate in some recipes (which deflate), and there were no adverse textural results, so I have been adding it for extra protein into just about everything I bake now. I too have searched repeatedly online, and no one seems to have answered this for the general public.

Answer (score 0):

I have a keto baking book and it states you can substitute with collagen powder or peptides.

Comment: Hi @user85464 and welcome to the Stack! This answer looks helpful. But a citation and some more details (is the substitution 1-to-1? are there any possible drawbacks?) would improve it. Thanks.

Comment: This is the start of a very good answer! I would love to see it fleshed out.